# Spiral problem, why does my loss increase in this neural network using Keras?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, spiral

I'm trying to solve the spiral problem using Keras with 3 spirals instead of 2 using a similar strategy that I used for 2. Problem is my loss is now growing exponentially instead of decreasing with the same parameters I used for 2 spirals (The neural network structure has 3 outputs instead of being binary). I'm not quite sure what could be happening with this issue if anyone could help? I have tried this with various epochs, learning rates, batch sizes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

from Question1.utils import create_neural_network, create_test_data

EPOCHS = 250
BATCH_SIZE = 20


def main():
    df = three_spirals(1000)

    # Set-up data
    x_train = df[['x-coord', 'y-coord']].values
    y_train = df['class'].values

    # Don't need y_test, can inspect visually if it worked or not
    x_test = create_test_data()

    # Scale data
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(x_train)
    x_train = scaler.transform(x_train)
    x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

    relu_model = create_neural_network(layers=3,
                                       neurons=[40, 40, 40],
                                       activation='relu',
                                       optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
                                       loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                                       outputs=3)

    # Train networks
    relu_model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

    # Predictions on test data
    relu_predictions = relu_model.predict_classes(x_test)

    models = [relu_model]
    test_predictions = [relu_predictions]

    # Plot
    plot_data(models, test_predictions)
```

And here is the create_neural_network function:

```
def create_neural_network(layers, neurons, activation, optimizer, loss, outputs=1):
    if layers != len(neurons):
        raise ValueError("Number of layers doesn't much the amount of neuron layers.")

    model = Sequential()

    for i in range(layers):
        model.add(Dense(neurons[i], activation=activation))

    # Output
    if outputs == 1:
        model.add(Dense(outputs))
    else:
        model.add(Dense(outputs, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=loss)

    return model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out, for the output data it isn't like a binary classification where you only need one column. For multi classification you need a column for each class you want to classify...so where I had y could be 0, 1, 2 was incorrect. The correct way to do this was to have y0, y1, y2 which would be 1 if it fit that specific class and 0 if it didn't.